# Can I import again in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux, javascript-import

For example in `App.js` I have

```
let store = createStore(CombinedReducers, applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware));

export { store }
```

When I do `import { store as mainStore } from './App'` in the other file I think it is going to run `createStore` before becoming `mainStore`. Can I do a reimport so this code is run again later? For this instance I do want to reset the `store` variable's state in between tests. And the `createStore` method can do just that.

Comment: No, modules are evaluated exactly once. (Unless you mess with the module loader, that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For this instance I do want to reset the **store variable's** state in
>   between tests. And the createStore method can do just that.

**Solution 1 :**

If you want to reset store variables then in redux you can **[dispatch action](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#example)** and set that particular store values to whatever you want

**Solution 2 :**  Doub't full

Create different store variables like

export const store1 = createStore(CombinedReducers, applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware));

export const store2 = createStore(CombinedReducers, applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware));